# Parsing Newlines, EOF as End-of-Statement Marker with ANTLR3

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

My question is in regards to running the following grammar in ANTLRWorks:

```
INT :('0'..'9')+;
SEMICOLON: ';';
NEWLINE: ('\r\n'|'\n'|'\r');
STMTEND: (SEMICOLON (NEWLINE)*|NEWLINE+);

statement
    : STMTEND
    | INT STMTEND
    ;

program: statement+;
```

I get the following results with the following input (with *program* as the start rule), regardless of which newline *NL* (CR/LF/CRLF) or integer I choose:

"; *NL*" or "32; *NL*" parses without error.
";" or "45;" (without newlines) result in EarlyExitException.
"*NL*" by itself parses without error.
"456 *NL*", without the semicolon, results in MismatchedTokenException.

What I want is for a statement to be terminated by a newline, semicolon, or semicolon followed by newline, and I want the parser to eat as many contiguous newlines as it can on a termination, so "; *NL NL NL NL*" is just one termination, not four or five. Also, I would like the end-of-file case to be a valid termination as well, but I don't know how to do that yet.

So what's wrong with this, and how can I make this terminate nicely at EOF? I'm completely new to all of parsing, ANTLR, and EBNF, and I haven't found much material to read on it at a level somewhere in between the simple calculator example and the reference (I have The Definitive ANTLR Reference, but it really *is* a reference, with a quick start in the front which I haven't yet got to run outside of ANTLRWorks), so any reading suggestions (besides Wirth's 1977 ACM paper) would be helpful too. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, Why did the answer that was here get removed before I had a chance to analyze it. Anyway, Bart Kiers's answer here (before he removed it) on using _fragment rules_ was what I needed.

Answer (score 7):

In case of input like `";"` or `"45;"`, the token `STMTEND` will never be created.

`";"` will create a single token: `SEMICOLON`, and `"45;"` will produce: `INT SEMICOLON`.

What you (probably) want is that `SEMICOLON` and `NEWLINE` never make it to real tokens themselves, but they will always be a `STMTEND`. You can do that by making them so called "fragment" rules:

```
program: statement+;

statement
 : STMTEND
 | INT STMTEND
 ;

INT     : '0'..'9'+;
STMTEND : SEMICOLON NEWLINE* | NEWLINE+;

fragment SEMICOLON : ';';
fragment NEWLINE   : '\r' '\n' | '\n' | '\r';
```

Fragment rules are only available for other lexer rules, so they will never end up in parser (production) rules. To emphasize: the grammar above will only ever create either `INT` or `STMTEND` tokens.